# how to reboot a python fileHandler

Tags: python, handlers

I have a file handler:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
fh = logging.FileHandler('file_name.log',mode='w')
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

After some time I want to copy the file and clear the original file so that the logger will keep adding data to the original file. Something like this:

```
shutil.dopy('file_name.log','another_file.log')
os.remove('file_name.log')
open('file_name.log','w')
```

This, of course doesn't work.
I'm working on python 3.2.
Can it be done?

Comment: Do you really want to copy the original file, clear it out, and start overwriting it? It's simpler, and more common to just move the file and start writing a new one. It's especially more simpler and more common when you're doing it in Python, which has that functionality built in to the `logger` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RotatingFileHandler` or `TimedRotatingFileHandler` instead.

http://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler